# ios - NSOutputStream doesn't write data

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoutputstream

I am downloading a file and writing its bytes to an `NSOutputStream`:

```
 self.outputFileStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:downloadFilePath 
 append:NO];    
 [self.outputFileStream setDelegate:self];
```

Then, in a `NSURLSession`'s `didReceiveResponse` callback:

```
[self.outputFileStream open];
```

And, once the first bytes received:

```
const uint8_t *bytes = (const uint8_t*)[data bytes];       
NSInteger bytesLeft = [data length];
NSInteger bytesWritten = -1;
do {
   bytesWritten = [self.outputFileStream write:bytes maxLength:bytesLeft];
   if (bytesWritten == -1) {
       break;
   }
   bytesLeft -= bytesWritten;
} while (bytesLeft > 0);
```

The execution stops the first time I try to write data to the stream: `write:maxLength:` returns -1.

To find out why this is happening, I have implemented a delegate method `handleEvent: eventCode:`.

For some reason, it only gets called if I place the following lines of code when initializing the stream:

```
[self.outputFileStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

and returns `NSStreamEventErrorOccurred` with `No such file or directory` description, although the directory is double-checked to be existing.